# What's the correct way to use multiple COUNT clauses in a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

My database teacher has given me the following interrogation to translate in a single query in SQL:

> Show, for every exam module, the number of students who got a mark between the values 18 and 21, the the ones who got a mark between 22 and 26 and in the end the ones who got a mark between 27 and 30.

The tables involved are:

```sql
    CREATE TABLE student(
        code CHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY,
        bachelor_course CHAR(3),
        name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        surname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        birth_date DATE NOT NULL,
        fiscal_code CHAR(16) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        photo BLOB,
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE module(
        code CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        description VARCHAR (100),
        university_credits TINYINT NOT NULL CHECK(university_credits > 0 AND university_credits < 13)
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE exam(
        student_code CHAR(6),
        module_code CHAR(3),
        teacher_code CHAR(6),
        exam_date DATE NOT NULL,
        mark TINYINT NOT NULL CHECK(mark > 0 AND mark < 31),
        notes VARCHAR(100)
    );
```

I've been trying for half a day and I think I'm near the correct answer. After searching on the web I found a way using multiple SELECT in the main one like this:

```sql
SELECT module.code, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM module m1 JOIN exam e1 ON m1.code = e1.module JOIN student s1 ON e1.student_number = s1.number WHERE e1.mark >= 18 AND e1.mark <= 21 GROUP BY m1.code) AS StudentNumber_18_21, (SELECT same as the first one but with 22 and 26 values in the WHERE clause) as StudentNumber_22_26, (SELECT same as the first one but with 27 and 30 values in the WHERE clause) as StudentNumber_27_30, FROM module;
```

The output should be like this:

```
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|ModuleName|StudentNumber_18_22|StudentNumber_22_26|StudentNumber_27_30|
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
//values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please share the same data as well. After reviewing your problem below is one of the options which you can use

```
SELECT m.code ,
         SUM(CASE WHEN e.mark >= 18 AND e.mark <= 21 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) StudentNumber_18_21,
         SUM(CASE WHEN e.mark >= 22 AND e.mark <= 26 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) StudentNumber_22_26,
         SUM(CASE WHEN e.mark >= 27 AND e.mark <= 27 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) StudentNumber_27_30,
    FROM Module m 
    INNER JOIN JOIN exam e ON m.code = e.module
    INNER JOIN dbo.Student s ON e.student_number = s1.number 
    GROUP BY M.code
 SELECT module.code,e.mark
```

Comment: Perfect! This worked for me! But, I don't understand why I cannot use COUNT clause which should do the same task as you emulated with SUM-CASE clauses...

Answer (score 1):

Your query is overly complicated because it is joining to `students` and that doesn't seem necessary.

Also, MySQL has a very convenient short-cut for counting values in different columns:

```
SELECT m.code,
       SUM( e.mark >= 18 AND e.mark <= 21 ) as StudentNumber_18_21,
       SUM( e.mark >= 22 AND e.mark <= 26 ) as StudentNumber_22_26,
       SUM( e.mark >= 27 AND e.mark <= 27 ) as StudentNumber_27_30,
FROM Module m INNER JOIN
     exam e 
     ON m.code = e.module
GROUP BY m.code
```

This works, because MySQL treats boolean expressions as numbers in a numeric context -- with "1" for true and "0" for false.